# Flexbox CSS Arrangment of Divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to arrange divs using Flexbox and not sure what I want to do is even possible.

Desired look at 769 pixels is to have column F expand down the entire height of the container on the left, and G and H stack on top of each other to the right (run the code snippet to see).

Once the screen resolution gets below 768 the look I have currently is the desired result for that view (F and G on the same row and H below spanning the width of both).

```css
body {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.wrap {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px;
}
.title {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.card {
    margin: 20px 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-color: #fff;
}
.container.show-border, .element.show-border {
    border: 1px red solid;
    padding: 9px;
}
.content {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: calc(1vw + 1em);
}

@media (max-width: 375px) {
.content {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 0;
    text-indent: -9999999em;
}
}
.container, .element {
    padding: 10px;
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.col {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.element {
    min-width: 100px;
}
.content {
    flex: 1 100%;
}
.structure {
    min-height: 480px;
}
.structure-2 {
    flex: 1 44.4444444444%;
}
.f {
    flex: 1 25%;
    min-height: 480px;
}
.g {
    flex: 1 75%;
}
.h {
    flex: 1 75%;
}

@media (max-width : 768px ){
.structure-2,  .f, .g {
    flex: 1 50%;
    min-height: 480px;
}
.h {
    flex: 1 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
}
}
```

```html
  <p>This table is a visual representation of what I am trying to accomplish at 769 px or higher. The view at 768 pixels or lower is as I want.</p>
  <table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">F</td>
      <td>G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="container card">
        <div class="flex row structure">
          <div class="flex row structure-2">
            <div class="flex element f">
              <div class="content"> F </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex element g">
              <div class="content"> G </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex element h">
              <div class="content"> H </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think for the first one, you would need to flex direction column with column wrap, then use the media query to change to rows for the second one

Comment: This seems the perfect scenario for [grid layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), do you need to use flexboxes?

Comment: Updated the media query to 768px, sorry that was an odd typo on my part. I will look at grid layout too. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the flex-direction after 769px;. Something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 769px ){
    .structure-2{
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .element{
       flex: 1 1 auto;
       width:50%;
    }

    .f{
        height:100%;
    }
}
```

P.S. I changed also your `@media (max-width : 1608px )` to `@media (max-width : 768px )` to remove some conflicts.

```css
body {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.wrap {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px;
}
.title {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.card {
    margin: 20px 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-color: #fff;
}
.container.show-border, .element.show-border {
    border: 1px red solid;
    padding: 9px;
}
.content {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: calc(1vw + 1em);
}

@media (max-width: 375px) {
.content {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 0;
    text-indent: -9999999em;
}
}
.container, .element {
    padding: 10px;
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.col {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.element {
    min-width: 100px;
}
.content {
    flex: 1 100%;
}
.structure {
    min-height: 480px;
}
.structure-2 {
    flex: 1 44.4444444444%;
}
.f {
    flex: 1 25%;
    min-height: 480px;
}
.g {
    flex: 1 75%;
}
.h {
    flex: 1 75%;
}

@media (max-width : 768px ){
    .structure-2,  .f, .g {
        flex: 1 50%;
        min-height: 480px;
    }
    .h {
        flex: 1 100%;
        min-height: 480px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 769px ){
    .structure-2{
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
 
    .element{
       flex: 1 1 auto;
       width:50%;
    }

    .f{
        height:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container card">
    <div class="flex row structure">
      <div class="flex row structure-2">
        <div class="flex element f">
          <div class="content"> F </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex element g">
          <div class="content"> G </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex element h">
          <div class="content"> H</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works! Thank you and thanks for catching the typo "1608" too.

Answer (score 0):

When device width is under 769px:

```
 - class ".f" will take the whole width - 100%

 - classes ".g, .h" will take the half width - 50%





  @media (max-width: 769px) {
   .f {
       flex: 1 100%;
      }
   .g,
   .h {
       flex:0 50%;
      }
  }
```

Comment: I doubt the answer is helpful to anyone without some sort of explanation as to how it works or what the code does. What is obvious to you is not to the OP (which is why the question was posted)